# Prove or disprove that for any $a, b, n\in \mathbb{N}^0$ satisfying $a ≤b≤n$,$ C(n,b)C(b, a) = C(n, a)C(n-a, b-a)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am having trouble figuring out how to prove this that claim is true or false. To be very honest, combination problems are not my strongest forte at all. So, I am having difficulty trying to start this.

Any tips or suggestions on how to start this proof would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the donkey way, i.e. writing it out with factorials and cancelling?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Imagine that you have $n$ white balls numbered $1$ through $n$. You want to paint $a$ of the red and $b-a$ of them blue. You can do this in (at least) two different ways.

- You can choose $a$ balls and paint them red. Then you can choose $b-a$ of the remaining white balls and paint them blue.
- You can choose $b$ balls to be colored. Then from those you can choose $a$ to paint red, after which you will paint the remaining $b-a$ chosen balls blue.

Each of these corresponds to one side of the identity that you want to prove (which *is* true). Can you see which is which, and explain why? That would prove the identity, since its two sides would just be two different legitimate ways of calculating the same thing.

**Note:** I like combinatorial proofs of combinatorial identities and think that they are very often more informative than more computational proofs, so I tend to emphasize them, but **Integrand**’s suggestion in the comments also works perfectly well.